# Accessing an iframe page through Apache's HttpClient

Tags: java, apache, iframe, httpclient

I've been working on parsing a website but am running into problems when one of the major pages I need to parse can only be found in an iframe.

I can see the URL to the parent page and have attempted many times to visit it through HttpGet (after being logged in of course and being able to visit any other account specific page), but it fails. In fact, the page that I am given is the page a user would get if they were not logged in at all. Yet in the line above my HttpGet execute for this iframe parent I show that I am logged in via cookies.

In short, how can I access an iframe parent page and stay logged in?

Comment: Please register an account so you can edit and leave comments on your posts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the fact that your logged cookie is not associated with the second request made by the iframe and thus redirecting you to the login page.

You should be able to view the iframe by requesting it seperately and passing it your logged cookie. eg

```
HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionId);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, after you suggestion I tried passing it the cookie again but it overwrites the JSESSIONID with a new value as soon as I execute a GET on the iframe parent.

Comment: When you say "overwrites". What is overwritten when? Please post the code you use to make the request in your initial question. The worst case scenario is that the iframe request creates a new unauthenticated session. Use the sessionid from your initial login request and GET the iframe content with that initial JSESSIONID. PS: you posted this as a answer but it should be a comment to my answer.